# Import product with attributes magento

Tags: php, magento, import, attributes, product

im using an import script that import's simple and configurable product to magento from xml.

The problem is that, imported simple products are i magento but they don't have attributes values assigned.

Import via APIv2 is working well bu it is to slow, that why i need to do this on model.

my question is:
Is This (code below) correct ? Meybe you have better, different metod to assigne attribute value to product  :-)

```
$product->setData('rozmiar',$Products['sizeId']);
$product->setData('kolor',$Products['colorId']);
```

my code:

```
$productCheck = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $products['sku']);
            if ($productCheck) {
                $productCheck->delete();
                //print_r('true !');
            }

            $color = attributeValueExists1('kolor',$Products['color']);
            $size = attributeValueExists1('rozmiar',$Products['size']);

            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
            $product->setCreatedAt(strtotime('now'));
            $product->setTypeId($products['type']);
            $product->setTaxClassId(0); 
            $product->setWebsiteIds(array(1));  
            $product->setAttributeSetId($products['attrset']); 
            $product->setSku($products['sku']);
            $product->setName($products['name']);
            $product->setDescription($products['description']);
            $product->setInDepth('');    
            $product->setPrice($products['price']);
            $product->setShortDescription($products['description']);
            $product->setWeight(0);
            $product->setStatus(1); 
            $product->setVisibility(1); 
            //$product->setMetaDescription($products['name']);
            //$product->setMetaTitle($products['name']);
            //$product->setMetaKeywords($products['name']);
            $product->setCategoryIds($products['categories']);
            $product->setKolor($color);                        
            $product->setRozmiar($size);                       
            //$product->setData('rozmiar',$Products['size']);
            //$product->setData('kolor',$Products['color']);
            $product->setStockData(array(
                   'use_config_manage_stock' => 0, 
                   'manage_stock'=>1, 
                   'min_sale_qty'=>1, 
                   //'max_sale_qty'=>2, 
                   'is_in_stock' => 1, 
                   'qty' => $products['qty']
                   )
            );

            $product->save();
```

Importing products via Soap APIv2 im using

```
$result = $this->client2->catalogProductCreate($this->session, $type, /*$attributeSet['set_id']*/ '4', $kod, array(
        'categories' => $kategorie,  // array !!!!
        'websites' => array(1),
        'name' => $nazwa,
        'description' => $opis,
        'short_description' => $opis,
        'weight' => '1',
        'status' => '1',
        'url_key' => $nazwa,
        'url_path' => $nazwa,
        'visibility' => '1',
        'price' => $cena,
        'tax_class_id' => 1,
        'meta_title' => '',
        'meta_keyword' => '',
        'meta_description' => '',
        'stock_data' => array(  'manage_stock' => '1',              
                                'manage_stockSpecified' => False, 
                                'is_in_stock' => '1', 
                                'is_in_StockSpecified' => False, 
                                'qty' => $ilosc     
                            ),
        'additional_attributes' => $additionalattr
    ));     
    return $result;
```

Is additional_attributes different from $product->setData('rozmiar',$Products['sizeID']); ?
If it's not the same how can i add additional_attributes when importing products via catalog/product model ?

Comment: All you need to do is to add the attributes to the attribute sets if they are not already there.

Comment: The problem is that they are added to the atributeSet :/. When im login to admin panel i can see the attributes on a product page but there are no value selected. I can manually select the value.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to assign corresponding attributes to products. Then after you can use import script to save those attributes value to products.